# How do I ask for examples without my question being deleted for "recommendations" violations?

Tags: discussion

How do I ask for examples of discussion and debate within literacy circles as part of a larger, more in depth, answer, so that a moderator won't misunderstand the question and delete it as a "recommendation" violation?

I ask this based on the premise that the desired answer is in no way a "recommendation" violation, and that any deletions on these grounds would be due to a misunderstanding, with the intention of avoiding that misunderstanding.

Answer (score 8):

*Ask a specific question* and good answers will include examples, references, scholarly debates, and so on, if appropriate. So don't ask "Give me some references/examples/discussions pertaining to *Question*", just ask "*Question*"!

Some examples:

- Don't ask: "List some discussions of Odysseus' infidelity in the *Odyssey*"
  Do ask: "[Was Odysseus considered unfaithful to his wife in the *Odyssey*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/1674/3003)"
- Don't ask: "Give me references to textual criticism of the 'solid flesh' line in *Hamlet*"
  Do ask: "[Why are there three different versions of the 'solid flesh' line in *Hamlet*?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/15062/3003)"
- Don't ask: "List some citations related to the location of Homer's Ithaca"
  Do ask: "[Where was Homer's Ithaca?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/5971/3003)"

A direct question is more engaging: it's about literature, not about the academic study of literature, and it gives people writing answers more freedom to deploy their own arguments and style, rather than simply carrying out a literature survey.

So in the particular case that prompted this question on Meta,

- Don't ask: "List discussions of Lovecraft's use (or lack of use) of unreliable narrators"
  Do ask: "How reliable are Lovecraft's narrators?"
  Or better still, something like: "How reliable is the narrator in *The Shadow over Innsmouth*?" (the more specific, the better: you can always generalize later)

Comment: I've had questions like all of those shot down before for being open ended or opinion based.

Answer (score 4):

Asking for examples is rather difficult on Stack Exchange, but sometimes there is a way around the "give-me-some-examples-of-X taboo":

- The question "Most important papers on Beowulf or a lit review on Beowulf scholarship" was closed as inappropriate, but rewording it as [Approaching Beowulf scholarship - how to begin?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/11884/2191) made it acceptable.
- The question "List some academic critics who took authorial intent seriously" would not have worked, but [Was authorial intent ever taken seriously in academic literary theory?](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/6744/2191) was perfectly OK.
- "Give some examples of second-person novels" would not have worked, but [Earliest second-person novel](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/18375/2191). Questions of the type "Earliest example of x" has been used on several occasions to get around the recommendation issue. It often generates different answers, which thereby actually leads to a list of (early) examples.